# How can I show item menu description (note field) in joomla 3.8.1?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

In older versions of Joomla I used this code

```
$span = $item->note;
if (!(empty($span))) {
        $span = '<span class="lidesc">'.$span.'</span>';
    } else {
        $span = null;
        }
```

which I added in menu module files and adding

```
<?php echo $span; ?>
```

in switch operator.

But in the latest version of joomla I can't understand how to 'echo' menu item description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In menu module files need to add code to $linktype .

```
$linktype = $item->title . '<span class="lidesc">' . $item->note .'</span>';
```